# pdfkit.js not drawing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdfkit

How can I draw an image on a pdf using pdfkit? I try loading my source from my folders and I get this error:

> TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

my code:

```
var pdfdocument   = new PDFDocument({ margin: 30 });
pdfdocument.image('/test.png', { width:550 });
```

Comment: Are u have installed node.js and npm ? `fs` is node.js module. It seems you do not have node.js properly installed. Or maybe `pdfkit.js` requires different version of node.js.

Comment: I can print svg canvas to PDF with the same library, using the same method .image. I think node.js is ok, anyway I will try to install it.